# mips exception handling beq not working

Tags: error-handling, exception, mips

I am trying to find an exception by comparing the t0 value. I must have something wrong on the hex numbers that i compare the t0 value..do anyone know?

```
sw $v0 save0

mfc0 $t0 $13
srl $t0 $0 2
andi $t0 $t0 0x7c

beq $t0 0x00000008 bad_address_load
beq $t0 0x0000000a bad_address_store
beq $t0 0x00000012 break_instruction
beq $t0 0x00000014 bad_instruction
beq $t0 0000000018 overflow
beq $t0 0x0000001a trap_instruction
j else
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you've shifted `$t0` 2 bits to the right to get the `ExcCode` in bits 4:0, the mask you use for `andi` should be `0x1f`. And the immediates you compare against in `beq` should be 4, 5, 9, ... instead of 8, 10, 18, ...